# Android application search doesn't like C#

Tags: bug, android-app

If I try to search `c#` in the mobile app I get results which, basically, ignore the #

Comment: As a workaround, the search of `[c#]` for the tag does seem to operate correctly.

Comment: on the main site, searching for short words/phrases that match tags exactly defaults to a tag search.  If that's not happening in the app, that might be the actual bug.

Comment: Not repro'd on SE app v1.0.82 (beta). Searching `c#` is automatically converted to `[c#]` (as psubsee2003's comment)